# Convergence of a complex series invoving exp

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

For what $k$ does the following series converge: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i kn}}{n}$$

According to the ratio test it converges when $L=\left|e^{ik}\right|<1$

But $L=\left|e^{ik}\right|=\left|\cos(ik)+i \sin(ik)\right|=\sqrt{\cos^2(ik)+i \sin^2(ik)}=1$
So, does it mean that the series diverges?
Wolframalpha says, that the series converges when $e^{im(k)} \ge 1$ and $e^{ik} \ne 1$.
How to get this result?

Comment: Take $ k = mπ $, then it will be a alternating series. So, converge.

Comment: So, it can be converge when $|e^{ik}| = 1 $

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\left|e^{ik}\right|=e^{\operatorname{Re}(ik)}=e^{-\operatorname{Im}k}$. So, if $\operatorname{Im}k>0$ your series converges and if $\operatorname{Im}k<0$ it diverges, by the ratio test.

If $\operatorname{Im}k=0$, that is, if $k\in\Bbb R$, it still converges, unless $k=0$ (it is clear that your series diverges if $k=0$, since then it's the harmonic series). That follows from Dirichlet's test: the partial sums of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{ikn}$ are bounded and the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a real monotonic sequence which converges to $0$.

Comment: Why $\left|e^{ik}\right|=e^{re(ik)}$?

Comment: If $z\in\Bbb C$, and if $z=x+yi$ with $x,y\in\Bbb R$, then\begin{align}|e^z|&=|e^{x+yi}|\\&=|e^xe^{yi}|\\&=e^x|\cos(y)+\sin(y)i|\\&=e^x\sqrt{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}\\&=e^x\\&=e^{\operatorname{Re}z}.\end{align}